# AngularJS - Not getting anything in html page while using angularjs drag and drop list library

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to implement drag and drop feature in my project. For this, i'm using [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) and here is the [demo](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple) of that feature. I'm not getting anything the html page. I tried to get the list on without the related CSS and it worked fine (commented that chunk of code).

Can anyone provide solution for this issue, why i'm not getting anything on the html without having any error on the console.

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="./script.js"></script>
        <script src="./angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="demo">
        <div ng-controller="SimpleDemoController" class="simpleDemo">
            <ul dnd-list="list">
                <li ng-repeat="item in list" dnd-draggable="item"
                    dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
                    dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                    dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
                    ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}">
                    {{item.label}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- <ul ng-repeat="item in models.lists.A">
                <li>{{item.label}}</li>
            </ul> -->


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

var SimpleDemoController = function($scope) {

    $scope.models = {
        selected: null,
        lists: {"A": [], "B": []}
    };
    console.log($scope.models.lists.A, $scope.models.lists.B);
    // Generate initial model
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        $scope.models.lists.A.push({label: "Item A" + i});
        $scope.models.lists.B.push({label: "Item B" + i});
    }

    // Model to JSON for demo purpose
    $scope.$watch('models', function(model) {
        $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
    }, true);

};

demo.controller('SimpleDemoController', SimpleDemoController);
```

**css**

```
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] {
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndDraggingSource {
    display: none;
}
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: block;
    min-height: 42px;
}

.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li.selected {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    color: #3c763d;
}
```

Comment: You're using `dnd-list="list"`, but you've never defined `list` - it's probably being treated as an empty array. For the list items you are using `ng-repeat="item in list"` so there is nothing to iterate over. This is why nothing is showing up in your view. I'm guessing you should replace all occurrences of `list` with `models.lists.A`, but it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing. Are you just trying to use `dnd-list` as a way to reorder a single list and not drag and drop between lists?

Comment: Follow this implementation https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/NwleL2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "dndLists" in demo variable(angular module)

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', ["dndLists"]);
```